# How to attribute multiple developers when submitting an app to the app store?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

Two of us worked on the same iphone app.  Neither of us has submitted one in the past so we're not sure of the process.

We'd like it if both of us are attributed.  How can we best go about that being that we both have individual developer accounts with Apple and we're not a company?

What is displayed under the app title in the app store?  Is that the company name, seller name, copyright name, or ?  Is the company name the same as your individual name?  Can you change it on a per app basis?  What is displayed at the bottom of app, under the images?

I've searched everywhere and can't find answers.  Thank you!

Comment: I think this is a good question but off topic for Stack Overflow. If I were you I'd go to your state's Department of Commerce or equivalent and find out your options for starting, e.g. an LLP or LLC. I know my state has a nice guide to starting a small business and lays out your options. After you've taken care of the legal aspects set up an app store account in the name of the company. That's what I'd do anyways, good luck!

Comment: Hi @CarlVeazey; I don't think this is off topic for Stack Overflow, myself, since this is a question that many programmers who work in groups might run into.  Better to try to provide a useful answer here than to merely close it.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann I respect that and see your point. This one is definitely a tough call. And to be fair I gave a suggestion in the comments. If you don't feel that my comment is useful you're entitled to that but naturally I disagree :). Thank you for raising the point though, I do appreciate other views on what is and isn't in scope and you have me more carefully considering questions related to problems unique to the programming profession.

Comment: Well there's one more close vote left so I expect it'll be closed pretty quickly.  Hopefully I was able to answer the question well enough for KrisF to make a good decision about how to proceed.

Comment: I had a feeling this question might get closed...but I couldn't think of anywhere better to ask it.  Any suggestions on where this question might be better suited to be asked?  Unfortunately an LLP or LLC is a bit of overkill for our purposes.  We only have this one app that we jointly created and we're releasing it free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the app can only be submitted under one Apple Store account.  It's up to you to decide who *"owns"* the account.

If this were my app, I'd buy a new Apple Developer account, decide upon a nice sounding name for my team of two developers and then both developers should have access to the account so you can track sales & progress & crashes, etc.

Once you decide upon a name for the account -- that is, how it's displayed on the App Store -- that's what it's going to be all further apps submitted on that account going forward.  It's really hard (if not impossible) to change it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice... Do you know what name gets displayed under the app title?  Is that the individual's name?  Can it be changed on a per app basis?  This is a free app we've made and we'd rather not spend 99/year to maintain it.

Comment: The name you choose for the App Store account (which you'll be required to type in when you submit your app) stays the same for the life of the account.